# How does selling my house affect my credit?

Tags: mortgage, credit-score

I bought a house 3 years ago. Since then I have made all my payments on time without ever missing a payment.

From my understanding, this is good for my credit.

I am now selling my house. How will this affect my credit?

I will not be making payments on a mortgage anymore so will my credit not be as good as it would had I not sold?

Comment: If you're not making payments anymore, you no longer need a credit score. Every so often you will check to make sure no one is stealing your identity, but after a while the website will throw an error when you go to check, and that will be reassurance that no one is tracking up dents in your name.

Answer (score 4):

Simply selling your house should not affect your credit. Having fewer types of credit (i.e. no mortgage) might ding you a TINY amount, but the effect would be so trivial it isn't worth even paying attention to.

Answer (score 2):

It will not have an immediate effect, other than lowering your total outstanding debt. This is good. Over time, however, without making the mortgage payment every month your credit will gradually slide down.

You'll be fine.

-tjw

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the average age of your lines of credit, this may impact your credit score either way. According to [creditkarma](http://creditkarma.com), the larger the average age is, the better the credit:

[image: Impact of average age of accounts on credit score]